# twos complement range in c

Tags: c, memory, binary

I calculated that the twos complement range of possible numbers to store in an int data type is +32767 to -32768, than I went on CodeBlocks and gave an int a value 
bigger than 32767 and it worked!

I know that if you give an array more values than declared it will take more 
bits than it is supposed to thus destroying another variable.
 **My question is** does the same thing happen when I give a datatype a value outside of its 

twos complement range? if not than what happens...

Comment: Nothing happens. In all probability your datatype `int` is actually 32 bits in size. Try printing `sizeof(int)` and see. When you declare an int, you're occupying *four* bytes. You may need to take care if you are allocating memory structures believing that an integer is two bytes in size.

Answer (score 0):

The **minimum** size for `int` is 16 bits, which can hold -32,768 to +32,767. Its actual size varies from OS to OS, from compiler to compiler. The ISO C standard requires that `int`s be able to hold at least -32,767 to +32,767, but doesn't limit it to only those values.

It is allowed to be larger, and is on any modern 32-bit or 64-bit OS. 20 years ago in 16-bit DOS you would have seen 16-bit `int`s, but on any modern OS it'll typically be 32 bits.

If you overflow a `signed int` the behavior is undefined. In theory, the compiler can do anything, because conforming C programs aren't supposed to trigger overflow. In practice, the value will usually wrap around from positive to negative, or vice versa.

Overflowing `unsigned int`s is well-defined. Values are guaranteed to wrap. If `unsigned int` is 16-bits then `65535U + 1U == 0U`. If it's larger than 16-bits then `65535U + 1U == 65536U` (no overflow).

Comment: what does that mean *the minum size*?